# Bad minute in crontab?

Tags: cron, crontab, syslog

I get the following error in my syslog:

```
Oct 17 13:14:03 tracker cron[873]: (*system*) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
Oct 17 13:14:03 tracker cron[873]: Error: bad minute; while reading /etc/crontab
```

I don't see any bad minutes though! My `crontab` file is:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 18   * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 18   * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 18   1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Comment: Which operating system and version? Older Unix systems might not support the syntax for setting environment variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `cat -v /etc/crontab` to check for unintended control characters.

Answer (score 3):

Cron tab requires at least the first and last lines of the file not to be actual cron instructions. You can put comments instead - such as those below in a file:

```
# START CRON JOB LIST
* * * * * /path/to/script/script1.sh
0 3 * * 0 /path/to/script/script2.sh
5 0 * * 1 /path/to/script/script3.sh
# END CRON JOB LIST
```

Install it like so

```
sudo crontab -u user /path/to/cron/file
```

This should work for you.

Comment: I add comment and first and last line so it work

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar issue with this error:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.MswKCq":0: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? n
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.MswKCq
```

Googled all round and found that this was the error due to the no space in log folder for cron i.e in /var.
Make sure to run `df -h /var/` and see if there is enough space there.

Comment: Seriously?  A problem with disk free space can cause an error message that says that there’s a syntax error in an existing, static input file?  Can you provide any evidence (e.g., a reference) that other people have observed this bug?

Comment: yes, the bad minute error can occur while updating the crontab due to the disk space. I have updated the post with the details.

Answer (score 1):

I have same error on Ubuntu 16.04. Problem have with empty assignment to MAILTO

```
MAILTO=
```

The problem I found with the help of [chkcrontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chkcrontab)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having issues on a Mac you can check your crontab for non-printing characters by typing

```
crontab -l | cat -e
```

or

```
sudo crontab -l | cat -e
```

if you have a root crontab.

Comment: The question doesn't mention a Mac.

Comment: Indeed it does not, but the question doesn't specifically indicate linux either. I don't see why you wouldn't want to cover how to do this on as many operating systems as possible.

Answer (score 1):

various online systems (eg cron.help) said that `0/5` was "every 5 minutes"
but crontab doesn't actually like that and I needed to do `*/5`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

solution is very simple but hidden mate.

goto

`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`

edit your crontab file via notepad++ then press `CTRL+F` then goto Replace tab.

then write in.
Find with `\r`
Replace with (this input should empty make sure no space etc)

then click replace all button.
There you go mate you issue resolve ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. But my case is I use the windows file to replace the file

`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`.

My solution is:

```
apt install dos2unix
dos2unix /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

or you use python code like

```
str.replace("\r\n", "\n")
```

to fix it.
Hope you doing well.